# How to setup Google Apps with ActionMailer with Rails 2.3.5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got Google Apps setup with email for my domain, and now I need to configure ActionMailer to use it. But the info I've found seems to be conflicting. Can anyone tell me how exactly to set it up with Rails 2.3.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problems and got it working with this:

Step 1. Add the following to your development environment:

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = true
ActionMailer::Base.default_charset = "utf-8"
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,
  :address            => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port               => "587",
  :domain             => "domain.com",
  :authentication     => :plain,
  :user_name          => "YOUR_USER_NAME", #should be you@domain.com
  :password           => "YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE"
}
```

The critical line is :enable_starttls_auto. You have to restart webrick after making changes here.

Step 2. Create a Model like project_mailer.rb

```
class ProjectMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  def confirmation(project)
    subject    'Your email subject'
    recipients project.email
    from       'you@domain.com'

    body       :project => "hi"
  end
end
```

Step 3. Create a View like /views/project_mailer/confirmation.html.haml (or .erb). This is just a standard view file.

Step 4. Add a line in your controller like:

```
ProjectMailer.deliver_confirmation(@project)
```